# how to change position of radio Button in radio group

Tags: android

how to create radio button group view  in that button like horizontal in pic, i tried xml file but does found proper tag in that....
this is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your RadioGroup, set:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Because RadioGroup inherits from LinearLayout

Comment: The smileys, you mean? Yes. Yesterday I answered a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351562/radiobutton-need-be-under-imageview/21352100#21352100). The trick now is to set the button drawable to null (android:button="@null").

Answer (score 1):

The [Android Documentation for Radio Groups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) mentions that it inherits from [Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). Searching for 'orientation' turns up the [android:orientation property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation).

> The default is horizontal.
>
> Must be one of the following constant values.
>
> ```
> Constant      Value   Description
> horizontal    0       Defines an horizontal widget.
> vertical      1       Defines a vertical widget.
> ```
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol orientation.

**So simply add this property to Radio Group:**

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```